# Запятая при уточнении

Tags: запятая

> Пять лет подряд, восьмого июля под
> открытым небом, на самой красивой
> возвышенности с уникальным и
> изумительным видом на реку Оку,
> проходит празднование Дня семьи...

Правильно ли расставлены запятые. Мне кажется, что запятая напрашивается после "июля" или же убрать запятую после "подряд". Что выделил автор запятой после "подряд" - мне не понятно. Если уточнение, то запятая после "июля", но как-то на уточнение не совсем похоже. Вобщем, я запуталась. Подскажите.

Comment: По-моему, нужно уточнить у автора, каждый ли год это празднование было именно восьмого июля. В зависимости от ответа будет разный строй предложения.

И о каком праздновании идёт речь: о том ли, которое будет проводиться в этом году, или же о том, которое было ранее? Почему употреблена форма наст. времени "проходит"?

Comment: Погуглил... Оказывается, День семьи всегда отмечается именно 8 июля. Вопрос свой снимаю.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Бедный читатель! Здесь иформации как минимум на два полновесных предложения.

Answer (score 2):

Слава, в худ. литературе вместо прошедшего времени может употребляться форма наст. времени, т.н. настоящее историческое (или настоящее повествовательное). А запятая не нужна: здесь разные обстоятельства (неоднородные): когда? - восьмого июля - обстоятельство времени, где? -  под открытым небом - обстоятельство времени.

Answer (score 0):

Пять лет подряд восьмого июля, под открытым небом, на самой красивой возвышенности с *уникальным и изумительным* (???) видом на реку Оку проходит празднование Дня семьи...

Я бы так расставил. Но что такое "уникальный и изумительный"?
Да и вообще фраза активно не нравится.